# Only 1 upvote to answer but got 18 points. How?

Tags: support, reputation, voting

I got 1 upvote like below:

[image]

But some how added one 18 points :
is it 1 upvote , 1 downvote , 1 upvote?

If its true then SE is not showing log of downvote ( -2 ) anywhere?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You got 2 upvotes and 1 downvote.

```
20 - 2 = 18
```

Visit [your reputation tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1487469/pramod-nikam-dev?tab=reputation&sort=time) to see it.

BTW when you reach 1k rep you can click on the post score to see upvotes and downvotes separately.

- [image: post score]